# Change Border and Color of Bar ggplot but only for one group

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to add borderlines for barchart. Specifically, the plot below has bars without borderlines. If I add `linetype` both groups will have be with borderlines but I need only 'Black' group with dashed black borderline, and keep 'White' group coloured but without borderline.

```
df1<- data.frame(
score = scores,
count=c(white,black),
race =rep(c("White","Black"),c(length(white),length(black))))

ggplot(df1, aes(score,count,fill=race)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill=race),stat="identity",position="identity") +
scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("#ff1212","#1212ff"), 0.25)) +
labs(title="Chart for Phil", y="Percent", x="Score")
```

Results from the solution below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, your example was not reproductible because of variables `scores`, `black` and `white` but I made one :

```
library(ggplot2)
df1<- data.frame(
  score = rep(1,1),
  count=c(8,5),
  race =c("White","Black"))

ggplot(df1, aes(score, count, fill=race, col=race, linetype=race)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=race),stat="identity",position="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("#ff1212","#1212ff"), 0.25)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black","black")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dashed", "blank")) +
  labs(title="Chart for Phil", y="Percent", x="Score")
```

Comment: Thank you. However, the bars should be specifically overlapping, not next to each other.

Comment: Hi Laura, have you tried with your data ? it should work. I edited my reproductible example to be closer to your data

Answer (score 2):

Add `linetype = ifelse(race == "Black", "dashed", "blank")` right into the aes function of geom_bar.